# ¿Qué código en PHP puedo usar para buscar dentro de un PDF con múltiples archivos?

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un buscador de resultados académicos, pero el programa que genera los informes los hace por institución y en el mismo archivo ingresa a todos los estudiantes, debo hacer que en el buscador al escribir el nombre o cualquier dato del estudiante me genere el resultado individual del estudiante, aunque este dentro un documento PDF que contiene varios resultados.
Les agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Si no tenes limitaciones de tiempo y recursos, podes implementarlo en PHP. Pero no veo una sola razón por la que hacer algo así. Intentaría acceder a los datos "del programa que genera los informes" mediante un select y no estar abriendo, leyendo, comparando, guardando y cerrando cada archivo....